# React Native and Firebase send data to database

Tags: database, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, native

I am very new to Firebase and I have been looking up how to simply send data to Firebase from React Native. So far I have figured out that you have to import

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase';
```

and have

```
const firebaseConfig = {
apiKey: "AAAAAAAAAAAA3HbIO0u6yxU5MsE6FM",
authDomain: "kokeilut.firebaseapp.com",
databaseURL: "https://kokeilut.firebaseio.com",
storageBucket: "kokeilut.appspot.com",
};
const firebaseApp = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
```

but the problem is that I don't know how to send data to database.

Please help me with this, my main point is to send Name and highscore of my application.

Comment: Unless you've tried something already and got stuck, I doubt anyone will do a better job than the Firebase documentation: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write

Comment: For security reasons, it's recommended not to post an actual apiKey.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I Strongly recommend you to read [Firebase JavaScript Documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write), which is much clear than my example. Please correct me if I am wrong.

The following is my example code.

This way will allow Firebase create a Unique Id for your object.

```
   firebase.database().ref(url).push(jsonObject).
   then((data) => {
    dispatch({type:"FULFILLED"})
    //success
   }).
   catch((err) => {        
    dispatch({type:"REJECTED"})
    //error
   });
```

This way will make you create a customerId for your object.

```
   firebase.database().ref(url+customerId).set(jsonObject).
   then((data) => {
    dispatch({type:"FULFILLED"})
    //success
   }).
   catch((err) => {
    dispatch({type:"REJECTED"})
    //error
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

1. First, install firebase: `npm install firebase`
2. Then import firebase to your project: `import * as firebase from 'firebase';`
3. Then you can write to a database, but make sure that you have created a database in firebase, and you gave permission to write and read.

```js
  firebase.database().ref('users/').set({
      username: "name",
      email: "email",
      profile_picture: "imageUrl"
    });
```